# New to FB dev, trying to get access token via Java (server-side flow) in local Eclipse/Tomcat environment

Tags: java, facebook, authentication

Developing locally with a tomcat server under eclipse.  Goal is to use RestFB API kit to access user info on server side using Java.   I've done a LOT of research across the web but I am stumped.

My app is set up with Site URL: 
http://localhost:8080/

Initial URL for user is:

`www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id=155730431154731&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A8080%2FSircolBase%2Ffboauth%2F&scope=user_about_me,friends_about_me,offline_access`

The user hits this URL and accepts the app.  FB responds to my redirect URL which is a servlet via the following URL:

`localhost:8080/SircolBase/fboauth/?code=Mf_kXCH3Lo5cGeBuWw_R1x_1b1EJmvoXJpieDqsOk2k.eyJpdiI6IkJvdHRIMmJJZUR0cXNIdFZCX1E5d0EifQ.bjPZvcmNVLhk4KcfRwJwWSYKv6GVOe9TbveHRRIEoQ3BwXneDAfTKyzY4jw2k8BdSOc19QjSNJ8PrEEyQ0Uuomh3f4Nn_GEk95wGGJcI6sLnFDIXyC0_n7IbeJeRtazN`

I parse the code in the servlet and then build the oAuth GET request, which is:

`graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?client_id=155730431154731&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A8080%2FSircolBase%2Ffboauth%2F&client_secret=xxxxxxd39227e77de9d8ef682abf299c&code=Mf_kXCH3Lo5cGeBuWw_R1x_1b1EJmvoXJpieDqsOk2k.eyJpdiI6IkJvdHRIMmJJZUR0cXNIdFZCX1E5d0EifQ.bjPZvcmNVLhk4KcfRwJwWSYKv6GVOe9TbveHRRIEoQ3BwXneDAfTKyzY4jw2k8BdSOc19QjSNJ8PrEEyQ0Uuomh3f4Nn_GEk95wGGJcI6sLnFDIXyC0_n7IbeJeRtazN`

I execute the GET in Java and the response comes back as:

`access_token=155730431154731|15d3fb5635abf840d87f7f75.1-570520241|kuj1yskauro43dmqspwh-rqktwa`

I take the access token and try to do 2 calls, from the servlet on my local server immediately in java:

`graph.facebook.com/me?access_token=155730431154731%7C15d3fb5635abf840d87f7f75.1-570520241%7Ckuj1yskauro43dmqspwh-rqktwa&format=json`

`graph.facebook.com/JonesJerryK?access_token=155730431154731%7C15d3fb5635abf840d87f7f75.1-570520241%7Ckuj1yskauro43dmqspwh-rqktwa`

Both return with:

`{"error":{"type":"OAuthException","message":"Invalid access token signature."}}`

What am I doing wrong?   Note that both redirect URL references along this sequence are encoded and identical.   Does the access_token above look like it is in the correct format?    Some have suggested that it is not.  Note that I am requesting 'offline_access' in this app.

Thanks for any tips.

Answer (score 1):

This seems way too complicated. You can use [RestFB](http://restfb.com/), or the [Facebook Java API](http://code.google.com/p/facebook-java-api/) which have already encapsulated all the technical details for doing this.

Comment: Thks for responding, but actually this is exactly what is dictated in the Facebook documentation at http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/ 

The link you provided is to an API that appears to be fading into oblivion.  I am trying to stay on the Facebook doc.

Comment: Yes I am planning to use that.  But in order to initiate the primary class an access_token is needed.  This is where my problem lies - in getting the access_token.  The steps above are how an access_token is obtain according to FB doc.